# dismiss multipleViewControllers in iOS 5 and above?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've an app which consists of a UITabBar with three views one of which is a UITableVIew. The first view that loads when the app boots is a UIView held within the UITabBar view. This view is a form for the user to fill in which takes them through five different screens. Previously I've been loading these as modal views one on top of the other and at the end dismissing them all when the user hits the final button like so:

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController      dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However since `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` no longer works and has been replaced with `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` I'm not really sure how to achieve this multiple dismissal of view controllers. I've tried adding the calls to parent view controller but that doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. Any advice would be much appreciated.  I'm also getting the message in the console: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch. Is this what's causing the problem?

Please note, this is the first time in ages I've been programming for iOS, I've been devoting most of my time recently to Arduino and interfacting electornics with coding so this is a bit of a steep refresher course I'm on.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your five view controllers are pushed onto a UINavigationController, then they can all be dismissed/popped with one command:

```
- (NSArray *) popToViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController 
                         animated: (BOOL) animated
```

[It doesn't appear that you are using a UINavigationController... but it wasn't entirely clear from your description.]

Comment: you're right, I'm not. I've edited the question ot make that clear. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I guess the next obvious question is should I be using a navigation controller? If so, why do I need one now when I didn't before/

Comment: I sorted the navigation controller and fixed it. Cheers!